# Line 6 POD X3 Functionality

Tags: sound

is there any way to install Line 6 POD X3 drivers on latest Ubuntu version so that I can start recording my band tracks?
If so, what's the current best recording-app choice for doing so?

Thanks, first time in the AskUbuntu community!

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this, but I found these instructions [here](http://nl.line6.com/supportarchivenew/thread/4031/). The link is a couple of years old but the software is still there.

First, some build tools are installed, such as Subversion (`svn`) for version control. Subversion then pulls the latest stable version of the driver from the Internet and places it in a separate directory `line6usb`. The next step is to build the driver and install it. If everything works, feel free to remove Subversion and the other build tools.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc make subversion alsamixergui linux-headers-generic
sudo svn co https://line6linux.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/line6linux/driver/trunk line6usb`
cd line6usb
sudo make install
```

Then you have to find your soundcard with:

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

This tells you how your Line 6 device viewed by the computer ('hw:' number). Replace 'hw:1' with whatever shows up for your sound card when you type:

```
alsamixergui -D hw:1
```

You HAVE to turn the 'monitor' slider all the way down or things will crash (unless the 'svn' site has a newer version that fixes this).

Answer (score -1):

In case someone needed an up-to-date link, here's a link to the repo:

```
svn co https://svn.code.sf.net/p/line6linux/code/ line6linux-code
```

svn can be installed by

```
sudo apt install subversion
```